# PowerShell script issue from ps1 file

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new in PowerShell so sorry for the question. I'm trying to run script from from ps1 file but it doesn't seems to work - empty variables. When I run the same script directly in Shell it works fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you wanted to, you could dot source the script, and then the variables will be set globally for you to examine.  Or pressing F5 in the ISE.

Comment: PLEASE, do not post pictures of text/code/errors/sample data in a _code oriented site_. why force others to squint to read your text when you already have the text ... **_as text_** and can simply post it into the question? [*frown*]

Comment: Please see: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell variables have ***scope***, which means that sometimes they exist, sometimes they don’t, and sometimes when they exist they have different values than at other times that they exist, and all of the above is true at the same time. This is a common concept in many programming languages, and you should read up about it. With respect to PowerShell, there is an explanation of [scope at Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6); there is also [a good explanation of PowerShell scope at HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/203778/how-scopes-affect-powershell-scripts/).

In your particular case, the variables in your .ps1 file only exist while the script file is running; once the script exits, the variables are no longer in scope.

Comment: This is the answer, @OP, the variable `$Credential` and everything else within that script **only last until the end of the script**.  Once the script completes, their values are removed from memory.  If you want it to persist, dot source the script instead like this.  `. C:\PathTo\YourScript.ps1'

Comment: @FoxDeploy You missed your ending grave accent